Why are Problem Solvers travel agents so expensive?
Unsure whether this is an appropriate question for this forum, but I was looking into ways to use road bike levers with v-brakes and stumbled on this reddit post.
The claim, which I have no reason to doubt, is that a single Problem Solvers Travel Agent was $15 6 years ago (at the time of the thread). However on the official website listing they're $28, and sometimes more from retailers!
Inflation has been bad, but I don't think it has been that bad. Does anyone have any insight into the huge price jump?
To be clear, I have no ill will towards Problem Solvers, I'm just curious why they can (or have to?) sell for so much higher than before.

As all why do we have to pay this questions, because they can get away with it.

Lol, I wasn't familiar with these devices and at first glance I was like, "what the heck do travel agents have to do with bikes?" :)

Asking problemsolvers would be your best course of action.
email addressinfo@problemsolversbike.com
Facebook
Unless someone from problemsolvers sees your post and gives an informed answer your question is likely to result in speculation.
Per Request - including the comment in my answer.

They got back to me remarkably quickly with the following answer:
"Inflation has it's impact all along the supply chain for an item, including increased cost of transportation over the pandemic, as well as import tariffs on products from certain countries."
Lucas Myers Commented


Now that the official answer is there, I can offer some speculation. The most likely explanation is that you're comparing manufacturer's suggested retail price to some nondescript online price. The MSRP is often inflated so that sellers can offer "discount" prices than look good when compared to MSRP but are still profitable.
Unfortunately Problem Solvers did not have MSRPs online 6 years ago so Wayback Machine does not help here but I could easily find offers for $5 and $10 online today. I don't know if they're scams, shops going out of business or shops clearing inventory that doesn't sell at normal price but those are still online prices.

Someone has designed, hand manufactured and tested many versions of the product, put hundreds/thousands of hours' time into that then gone through the effort to get them manufactured in production quantities, made packaging, built a website/commerce channel and distributed that product to retailers. They have made it their business to provide solutions to problems that are hard, expensive or impossible for a bike shop or DIY mechanic to solve and build a reputation on doing so cost effectively.
The risk of negative return is fairly high. If their solution is needed in large volume, the manufacturers are likely going to make a product that eliminates the problem (e.g. a Road lever compatible with V Brakes.). When this happens, the R&D costs that has yet to be recovered is lost. Some products recover their costs many times over, but that makes up for the ones that lose money. To stay in business, they need to dance a tightrope while reading a crystal ball - charge enough to remain profitable but charge too much and you damage brand reputation and reduce sales volumes and profitability.
It’s not about $1 of billet aluminium and a roller bearing, it’s about everything else.
Why have prices gone up - They gave a story about interest and inflation and tariffs, which all contribute, but ultimately, because to remain in business they felt they needed to increase price.

Warren Burton, please undelete now the answer has been edited.
